# Relative URL replace part of old url instead of add to old one in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url

I have a problem with relative url in django application.

I have structure of objects which look like this

```
Competitions/
    games/
    players/
    costs/
```

and urls to point to it

`competitions/` - list of all competitions

```
{% for comp in competitions%}
    <li  onclick=window.location.href='{{comp.pk}}'>
        comp.name
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

When I clik on one of this links I'm redirected to page `competitions/<competitions_id>`

`competitions/<int:competition_id>` - detail view of a competition

`competitions/games/<int:competition_id>` -  list of all game in picked competition

```
{% for game in games%}
    <li  onclick=window.location.href='{{game.pk}}'>
        game.name
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

So when I'm on url: competitions/games/1
which list all games in competition with id = 1

```html
<li onclick=window.location.href='1'> game1</li>
<li onclick=window.location.href='2'> game2</li>
<li onclick=window.location.href='3'> game3</li>
<li onclick=window.location.href='4'> game4</li>
```

And I click for example on game4 my url address is competitions/games/4 instead of competitions/games/1/4 can someone explain me why.

Comment: Two hints: 1/ always use the `{% url %}` tag (or the `reverse` function in Python code) - this way you get absolute urls (well, absolute paths at least) AND you can simply change your urls layout without having to fix code all over the place - and 2/ don't use javascript when a plain link would work (=> replace all your `onclick=window.location.href` stuff with proper links).

Comment: Not the answer but I would suggest you to design your urls like 
`/competitions/<int:competition_id>/games/` for listing all games in specific competition.

Comment: And then the detailed view of the specific game would look like `/competitions/<int:competition_id>/games/<int:game_id>/`

Comment: i have try that but the problem was the same. And i have there table instead  of list item and because  of this table i have javascript

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that url doesn't ends up with /